# how to make cardview list in Onsen UI?

Tags: html, angular, onsen-ui

A have HTML code like this and I want to implement it using card view with onsen UI.

```
<div *ngIf="content">
<div>
    <img src="https://monaca.io/img/logos/download_image_onsenui_01.png" alt="Onsen UI" style="width: 100%">
</div>
<div>
    <label>title : </label> {{content.title}}
</div>
<div>
    <label>Captio : </label> {{content.caption}}
</div>
```

When I'm not implementing the code with card onsen, I got the perfect data shown in the screen.

[image: without card onsen]

But, when I implement the code with card onsen, the card just show the latest data in the screen.

[image: with card onsen]

Why is it doing this? This is the code I am trying to implement with card onsen.

```
<ons-page>
<ons-card>
    <div class="content">
        <div *ngIf="content">
            <div>                        
                <img src="https://monaca.io/img/logos/download_image_onsenui_01.png" alt="Onsen UI" style="width: 100%">
            </div>
            <div>
                <label>title : </label> {{content.title}}
            </div>
            <div>
                <label>Captio : </label> {{content.caption}}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</ons-card>
```

Comment: Grammar and formatting